# Basic Tree Concept: Defining ancestors

Tags: data-structures, tree

[image]

What defines an ancestor? More specifically, would E be an ancestor to H? Or is it more simply that F,C,A are ancestors to H? Maybe even G? I would just like to clear up this simple concept.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

E is not an ancestor of H. It's an **uncle** because it's a **sibling** of F, which is the **parent** of H.

F,C,A are **ancestors** of H. That's true.

G is not relevant to H at all.

Tree structure relationship notation can be found here (according to Wikipedia)

> - A node's "parent" is a node one step higher in the hierarchy (i.e. closer to the root node) and lying on the same branch.
> - "Sibling" ("brother" or "sister") nodes share the same parent node.
> - A node's "uncles" are siblings of that node's parent.
> - A node that is connected to all lower-level nodes is called an "ancestor". The connected lower-level nodes are "descendants" of the
>     ancestor node.

Comment: What's the difference of an ancestor compared to a predecessor in a tree with directed edges?

Comment: G is a cousin to H.

Answer (score 3):

`F, C, A` are ancestors of `H` cause there exists a path from root `A` to node `H` and nodes `F, C, A` appear in the path. node `H` is called `descendant` of nodes `F, C and A`.