# How to find all node's ancestors in NetworkX?

Tags: python, dependencies, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a large `DiGraph` that consists of dependent jobs. For example, for the graph a>b>c, job c can run only once job b is completed. I tried to find a function that gets all c's upstream jobs (that is (a, b)). I used `DiGraph.predecessors`, but it only returns job b.

Is there a function that will list all c's upstream jobs?

How can I draw the dependency diagram for a leaf node (like job c)?

I have read the documentation but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 9):

It may seem strange, but this function is called [ancestors](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors.html) :)

`nx.ancestors(G, your_node)`

Comment: But be careful: `Note that most of these functions are only guaranteed to work for DAGs. In general, these functions do not check for acyclic-ness, so it is up to the user to check for that.` [from the documentation]

Answer (score 7):

Using [predecessors](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html#networkx.DiGraph.predecessors) will only return the nodes with a direct edge to the input node. Finding all node's [ancestors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094991/basic-tree-concept-defining-ancestors) can be done as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()

# G is:
#      e-->f
#      ^
#      |
# a--->b-->c-->d
#

G.add_edges_from([('a', 'b'),('b', 'c'),('c', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('e', 'f')])
T = nx.dfs_tree(G.reverse(), source='f').reverse()     

# T is: a-->b-->e-->f

pos = nx.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(T, prog='dot')
nx.draw_networkx(T, pos=pos, arrows= True, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

What we do is simply running DFS from the input node on the **reversed** directed graph, and then reverse the result again to get the edges in their original direction.

The last three lines are for drawing the result.

Comment: I am getting following error: `AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'predecessors'` @zohar.kom

Comment: @alper 'predecessors' works for `DiGraph` objects but not for `Graph` objects (directed vs. undirected graphs).

Comment: I am getting the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydot'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a recent project, where jobs were dependent on other jobs. I found the most reliable way to guarantee processing them in the correct order was to use the DiGraph method `topological_sort`.

Below is a minimal example, starting with the creation of the DiGraph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

# this function is optional
# just moves the node labels on the plot so they don't overlap the lines 
def nudge(pos, x_shift, y_shift):
    return {n:(x + x_shift, y + y_shift) for n,(x,y) in pos.items()} 

# start with a directed graph
dag = nx.DiGraph()

dag.add_edges_from(
    [
        ('root', 'a'), 
        ('a', 'b'),
        ('a', 'c'),
        ('b', 'd'),
        ('d', 'e'),
        ('d', 'f')
    ]
)

# plot the graph
pos = graphviz_layout(dag, prog="dot")
pos_labels = nudge(pos, -5, 15)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.margins(0.1)

nx.draw(
    dag, 
    pos=pos,
    ax=ax,
    with_labels=False,
    arrows=True,
    node_size=100, 
    arrowsize=20
)

labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(
    dag,
    pos=pos_labels,
    ax=ax,
    font_size=18,
    font_weight='bold', 
    font_color='orange',
    verticalalignment='bottom'
)
```

The output plot of the graph looks like:

[image]

Probably the best thing to do first is verify the graph is a directed acyclic graph:

```
nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(dag)
```

That will return True or False. Next, we can use `topological_sort` to retrieve the nodes in dependency order:

```
list(nx.algorithms.topological_sort(dag))
```

This returns:

`['root', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`

If you would instead like to have the edge pairs instead of just the nodes:

```
list(nx.topological_sort(nx.line_graph(dag)))
```

which returns:

`[('root', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'f')]`

Finally, if the jobs need to be in reverse order you can use `reverse`:

```
dag_reverse = dag.reverse()
```

Re-running the commands::

```
list(nx.algorithms.topological_sort(dag_reverse))
```

gives:

`['c', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'root']`

and:

```
list(nx.topological_sort(nx.line_graph(dag_reverse)))
```

gives:

`[('c', 'a'), ('e', 'd'), ('f', 'd'), ('d', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'root')]`